# Pandas | merge rows with same id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the example data set

```
id         firstname    lastname      email               update date
A1         wendy         smith         ws@mail.com        2018-01-02
A1         wendy         smith         smith@mail.com     2019-02-03 
A2         harry         lynn          lynn@mail.com      2016-04-03
A2         harry                       harylynn@mail.com  2019-03-12
A3         tinna         dickey        tinna@mail.com     2016-04-03
A3         tinna         dickey        tinna@mail.com     2013-06-12
A4         Tom           Lee           Tom@mail.com       2012-06-12
A5         Ella                        Ella@mail.com      2019-07-12
A6         Ben           Lang          Ben@mail.com       2019-03-12
```

I have sorted the data set by `id` and `update date`, I want to merge the rows with same `id`, if one row with empty value, fill the other one with same `id`, if confilct, use the latest one.  For rows with no duplicate `id` leave the empty cell as it is.

the output should be:

```
id         firstname    lastname      email               update date
A1         wendy         smith         smith@mail.com     2019-02-03 
A2         harry         lynn          harylynn@mail.com  2019-03-12
A3         tinna         dickey        tinna@mail.com     2019-03-12
A4         Tom           Lee           Tom@mail.com       2012-06-12
A5         Ella                        Ella@mail.com      2019-07-12
A6         Ben           Lang          Ben@mail.com       2019-03-12
```

my attempt was using `ffill()` to merge rows with empty and keep last duplicate, but the result seems to affect other cells which should have empty values(like lastname in A5 should be empty ).

```
df=df.ffill().drop_duplicates('id',keep='last')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

- [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) - Group DataFrame or Series using a mapper or by a Series of columns.
- [`.groupby.GroupBy.last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) - Compute last of group values.
- [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) - Replace values given in to_replace with value.

**Ex.**

```
df = df.replace('',np.nan, regex=True)
df1 = df.groupby('id',as_index=False,sort=False).last()
print(df1)

   id firstname lastname              email  updatedate
0  A1     wendy    smith     smith@mail.com  2019-02-03
1  A2     harry     lynn  harylynn@mail.com  2019-03-12
2  A3     tinna   dickey     tinna@mail.com  2013-06-12
3  A4       Tom      Lee       Tom@mail.com  2012-06-12
4  A5      Ella      NaN      Ella@mail.com  2019-07-12
5  A6       Ben     Lang       Ben@mail.com  2019-03-12
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`GroupBy.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) to only forward fill for the same group. Then use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['lastname'] = df.groupby('id')['lastname'].ffill()
df = df.drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')
```

Or in one line (but less readable in my opinion), using [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df.assign(lastname=df.groupby('id')['lastname'].ffill()).drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')
```

**Output**

```
   id firstname lastname              email update date
1  A1     wendy    smith     smith@mail.com  2019-02-03
3  A2     harry     lynn  harylynn@mail.com  2019-03-12
5  A3     tinna   dickey     tinna@mail.com  2013-06-12
6  A4       Tom      Lee       Tom@mail.com  2012-06-12
7  A5      Ella      NaN      Ella@mail.com  2019-07-12
8  A6       Ben     Lang       Ben@mail.com  2019-03-12
```

Comment: if other columns contain empty values that need to be grouped,  can I add more lines like `df['email'] = df.groupby('id')['email'].ffill()` ... before drop duplicates? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('id').ffill().drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')
```

output:

```
   id firstname lastname              email  update date
1  A1     wendy    smith     smith@mail.com  2019-02-03 
3  A2     harry     lynn  harylynn@mail.com   2019-03-12
5  A3     tinna   dickey     tinna@mail.com   2013-06-12
6  A4       Tom      Lee       Tom@mail.com   2012-06-12
7  A5      Ella      NaN      Ella@mail.com   2019-07-12
8  A6       Ben     Lang       Ben@mail.com   2019-03-12
```

Comment: because of `ffill()` , `id` won't be set as an index

Comment: @ Divya Dass    When I tried your code, I got an error `KeyError: Index(['id'], dtype='object')`  Do you know what might cause the error? thanks

Comment: @user2748930 Not sure why you are getting this error. Erfan also stated to have got this error earlier. This error means that `id` has become an index in your case. In my case it had become a column after I had used ffill(). Therefore, I used drop_duplicates() after this.
In your case `df.groupby('id').ffill().reset_index().drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')` might help. This will make `id` a column if it has become index in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `groupby`, `apply`, and `iloc`:

```
df.groupby('id', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill').iloc[0])

   id firstname lastname              email  update date
0  A1     wendy    smith     smith@mail.com  2019-02-03
1  A2     harry     lynn  harylynn@mail.com  2019-03-12
2  A3     tinna   dickey     tinna@mail.com  2019-03-12
3  A4       Tom      Lee       Tom@mail.com  2019-06-12
4  A5      Ella      NaN      Ella@mail.com  2019-07-12
5  A6       Ben     Lang       Ben@mail.com  2019-03-12
```

- `groupby` groups the dataframe by unique ids
- `fillna` fills all the NaN values with the row with non-NaN values
- `iloc[-1]` gets you the row with the latest data