# How can I aggregate rows together according to a selected column using a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation, string-aggregation

this is my first question in Stack Overflow.
I will water down the problem that I have at the moment. I am trying to clean a dataset for a User-based collaborative filtering recommendendation system.

Here's an oversimplication of the dataset I have with all the use-cases

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'name':    ['John' ,'Jane' ,'Joe'  ,'John' ,'Jane' ,   'Joe'],
                     'movie1':  [''     , 'bad' , 'avg' , 'nice', ''    , ''    ],
                     'movie2':  ['good' , ''    , ''    , ''    , 'poor', ''    ],
                     'movie3':  ['bad'  , ''    , 'good', ''    , ''    , ''    ],
                     })
```

From for how I sourced my data I know that even though John, Jane and Joe might repeat themselves any amount of times, they will never have more than one rating for any given movie.

I want to be able to aggregate repeated users into a single row so that my output in terminal looks like this:

```
 name movie1 movie2 movie3
0  John   nice  good    bad
1  Jane    bad  poor            
2   Joe    avg          good
```

This problem is very similar to this question but the difference is that I'm dealing with string objects and not numbers, therefore I can't use aggregation functions  [How can I "merge" rows by same value in a column in Pandas with aggregation functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826773/how-can-i-merge-rows-by-same-value-in-a-column-in-pandas-with-aggregation-func)

My real dataset has 4260 columns and 24169 rows, therefore I'm not capable of applying something like `df.groupby(['name','month'])['text'].apply(','.join).reset_index()` because it's not possible to write down all the column names. From: [Concatenate strings from several rows using Pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298178/concatenate-strings-from-several-rows-using-pandas-groupby)

I tried following the answers of this question but I either got errors or my dataframe stayed the same. [Pandas | merge rows with same id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218387/pandas-merge-rows-with-same-id)

Even though logically it didn't make sense, I tried using `data.groupby('name').ffill().drop_duplicates('name' ,keep='last')` and I got the following error = KeyError: Index(['name'], dtype='object')

Passing False to as_index inside the groupby gave me the exact same error `data.groupby('name', as_index=False).ffill().reset_index().drop_duplicates('name', keep='last')`

The closest that I've gotten has been this: `data = data.groupby('name', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill').iloc[0])`

The output that it gives me only deletes repeated rows but doesn't add the ratings to the leftover data:

```
   name movie1 movie2 movie3
0  Jane    bad              
1   Joe    avg          good
2  John          good    bad
```

Complete Code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'name':    ['John' ,'Jane' ,'Joe'  ,'John' ,'Jane' ,   'Joe'],
                     'movie1':  [''     , 'bad' , 'avg' , 'nice', ''    , ''    ],
                     'movie2':  ['good' , ''    , ''    , ''    , 'poor', ''    ],
                     'movie3':  ['bad'  , ''    , 'good', ''    , ''    , ''    ],
                     })
print('Baseline:')
print(data.head())

#data = data.join(data['name'])
#data.groupby('name').ffill().drop_duplicates('name' ,keep='last')
#data.groupby('name', as_index=False).ffill().reset_index().drop_duplicates('name', keep='last')
data = data.groupby('name', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill').iloc[0])
#data.groupby('name').ffill().drop_duplicates('name', keep='last')
#data =  data.groupby(['name'])[['movie1','movie2','movie3']].apply('.'.join).reset_index()
print('End result:')
print(data.head())
```

Comment: Welcome to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Nice effort to produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your code you have tried so far. Really appreciate! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `groupby_first`. The trick is to replace empty string by nan then rollback after selecting the first valid value:

```
>>> data.replace('', np.nan).groupby('name', as_index=False, sort=False).first().fillna('')

   name movie1 movie2 movie3
0  John   nice   good    bad
1  Jane    bad   poor       
2   Joe    avg          good
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks a ton I only got a warning but it did the trick! "PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  user_data = user_data.replace('',np.nan).groupby('user', as_index=False,sort=False).first().fillna('')"